# Crash when calling onRequestPermission On Android Nougat java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, permissions

so my app working perfectly fine with all devices but today i got a really confusing crash report.

**i have 1 Activity , 2 Fragments.**

**HomeFragment** is the one that causing this crash .

**here's the crash report:**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 

  at mypackage.myappname.HomeFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult (HomeFragment.java:432)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult (FragmentActivity.java:804)

  at android.app.Activity.requestPermissions (Activity.java:4296)

  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (ActivityCompat.java:507)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.requestPermissionsFromFragment (FragmentActivity.java:894)

  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onRequestPermissionsFromFragment (FragmentActivity.java:953)

  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requestPermissions (Fragment.java:1132)

  at mypackage.myappname.HomeFragment.onPickClicked (HomeFragment.java:339)

  at mypackage.myappname.HomeFragment.onClick (HomeFragment.java:1150)

  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6261)

  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23752)

  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

**these few lines are the important part:**

```
  at mypackage.myappname.HomeFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult (HomeFragment.java:432)


  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (ActivityCompat.java:507)



  at mypackage.myappname.HomeFragment.onPickClicked (HomeFragment.java:339)

  at mypackage.myappname.HomeFragment.onClick (HomeFragment.java:1150)
```

**at line 432 i handle onRequestPermissionResult :**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,@NonNull String[] permissions,@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);


        switch (requestCode) {

            case GALLERY_PERMISSIONS_REQ_CODE:

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        openGallery();
                }
                imgGalleryCV.setClickable(true);
                break;


        }
    }
```

**and at line 339 here where i call the requestPermission :**

```
requestPermissions(galleryPermission,GALLERY_PERMISSIONS_REQ_CODE);
        imgGalleryCV.setClickable(false);
```

**my String[] galleryPermission :**

```
private final static String[] galleryPermission = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
```

**i don't think there's something wrong with my code .
so is it a bug or android is just trying to confuse me ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check if the grantResults size is more then 0 like this

```
  if (grantResults.length > 0){

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        openGallery();
                }
                imgGalleryCV.setClickable(true);

}
```

Comment: could it be that? then why it's not causing any ptoblem with all devices only today 1 report with nougat , i mean i tested deny permissions and no errors

Answer (score 1):

Call the parent method `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);`
just if there's not a match with the request code you're receiving:

```
switch (requestCode) {
        case GALLERY_PERMISSIONS_REQ_CODE:

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    openGallery();
            }
            imgGalleryCV.setClickable(true);
            break;

        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
            break; 
}
```

Here you have an example of RuntimePermissions usage: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/system/runtimepermissions/MainActivity.java

Comment: but what's wrong with calling it anyway on the top ?

Comment: It gives a default behavior when you don`t know how to manage the given request code. Also consulting the API, I found the following: **Note:** It is possible that the permissions request interaction with the user is interrupted. In this case you will receive empty permissions and results arrays which should be treated as a cancellation. Perhaps is somehow what is happenning in your situation. Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback

Comment: thank you so much for the helpful info in your last comment , i choosed the other answer because it solving the problem too by checking the length of grantresults .